# Error with site JS for Civicrm 5.8.0

Tags: civievent

Hi we suddenly started getting a </body>\r\n</html>","help_post":"\r\n\r\n\t error in the event info page and payment contribution page during editing.

not sure why this started happening.

Has this happened to anyone else, seems like a js error as i can see a few reds in the console.

Civicrm 5.8.0 and drupal 7.60

Comment: Could you please edit the question to say what the console errors are?  They almost certainly have useful information.

Answer (score 1):

This had to do with the Google Tag Manager module for Drupal. Updating to the latest version resolved this issue.